# How to call and use a function contained in another class file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm having a strange problem, I need to call a `void` function called `insertCommunication` contained in a class file named `MBUser.m` from another class, named `ProdottoViewController.m`. Since this function is not in `ProdottoViewController` but in `MBUser.m` I need to do those step to import the class properly, correct me if I'm wrong:

1. Import the `.h` file of `MBUser` in `ProdottoViewController.m`, like this:

   ```
   #import "ProdottoViewController.h"
   #import "MBUser.h"

   @interface ProdottoViewController () {

   }
   ```
2. Create a `@class` of `MBUser` like so:

   ```
   @class MBUser;
   /* This class declaration is placed between the #import(s) and the @Interface of ProdottoViewController.m*/
   ```
3. Create a `@property` of `MBUser` in `ProdottoViewController.m`

   ```
   @property (strong, nonatomic) MBUser *userClass;
   ```
4. `alloc` and `init`-alize MBUser, in this case I do this in the `viewDidLoad` function:

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];

       _userClass = [[MBUser alloc] init];
   }
   ```

This code works, compiles and Xcode gives me no error at all, but when I try to call the function it returns `nil` [even the other objects inside MBUser] even if `MBUser` is correctly allocated as you can see here:

[image]

Can you please help me?

**EDIT:** MBUser.m's `init` method

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            dictCache = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        });

        logined = NO;
        allowLogin = YES;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Did you initialise all these objects in `MBUser` `init` method?

Comment: What do you mean? I did only the steps I wrote in the question, do I need to do something else? Thanks for your comment @AnushaK

Comment: I am still not sure if the function you want to call is public or not.

Comment: @antonio Well I'm 100% sure that other class in the project I'm working call MBUser.m's functions correctly and they do all the same things I did in my ViewController but this doesn't work :-/. If other classes are able to call that function it means that that function is public, right?

Comment: Can you post the `init` method in `MBUser` class?

Comment: @AnushaK Sure :-), I will update the question :-)

Comment: Right, as long as the "other classes" are not subclasses or categories of MBUser.

Comment: @AnushaK Posted :-), (at)antonio mhmm I don't know this :-/

Comment: You are not initialising your other properties like `pw`, `branchCity` etc in `init` method. So how will you get the value for that properties just after the `init` method call?

Comment: @AnushaK Well I just need to call that method, insertCommunication, I don't need those properties :-/

Comment: What you mean by `when I try to call the function it returns nil`?

Comment: I mean that when I try to call the function it doesn't work properly :-/, I think because in the viewDidLoad MBUser has a lot of nil properties

Comment: @AnushaK can you tell me at least if those steps are correct?

Comment: If your method `insertCommunication` is an instance method and you declared it in `MBUser.h` file you can definitely call that method like  `[_userClass insertCommunication];`

Comment: How are you calling your method? You should call the method on the instance like so: `[_userClass insertCommunication];`

Comment: Are you getting a crash when you call [_userClass insertCommunication]; if not that means the call was a success. One you mentioned that the return type of the method is void and then you said it returns nil. Could you please clarify more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to `alloc` and `init`-alize the `MBUser` class only when needed and not in the `viewDidLoad` function. The steps I posted in the question was right, though. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

1. You must nil your *userClass* somehow. To find out what is going on add dealloc method (`- (void)dealloc`) to your MBUser class and put there breakpoint to check when it's being deallocated.
2. You don't need *@class MBUser;* in a file in which you've made import of that class. *@class* is for forward declaring classes in header files.